# How to retrieve ephemeral storage kubernetes metric via client-go and golang

Tags: go, kubernetes, metrics, client-go

I am able to fetch CPU and memory usage of a pod in a Kubernetes cluster with client-go using the following piece of code.

```
    podContainers := podMetric.Containers
    for _, container := range podContainers {
        cpu += container.Usage.Cpu().MilliValue()
        mem += container.Usage.Memory().ScaledValue(6)
    }
```

But having trouble getting ephemeral storage usage.

```
container.Usage.StorageEphemeral() //Gives me 0 every time.
```

How do I get the storage usage?

Even `kubectl top pod` command does not give the storage usage. Is there a limitation to provide storage usage from the Kubernetes side?

Comment: May be this is of help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52763291/get-current-resource-usage-of-a-pod-in-kubernetes-with-go-client